# Pop-up authorization in HTML

Tags: html, css

I recently wrote some code for a pop-up sign in and sign up. But I am having trouble as I want to hide overflow-y when someone is signing up using my pop-up.

[image]

```css
#Login {
  background: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
}

#okno1 {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 2px solid #3A5156;
  color: Black;
  font-family: Ubuntu;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#Login:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="Login">
  <div id="okno1">
    Вход<br>
    <a href="#" class="close1"><img src="Krest.png" id="Krestik1"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`overflow-y: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):

```css
:root,
html,
body {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It works, but it blocks the page scrolling in general, but I need it to block only when the login pop-up window. The image shows that with a pop-up window where the site is also darkened in the background, the user can scroll and because of this it turns out not quite as intended.

Comment: To make it work as a response to an event, you'll have to need some JavaScript code as well. For example, when the user opens the popup, you can put some class on `html` element, which would trigger these styles.

Comment: Could you help with a script?